# Android - Getting camera LED to strobe with handler?

Tags: android, camera, switch-statement, led, alternate

I am using a timed alert (working fine) to try and run code that will quickly switch camera flash LED between off and on positions.

I'm trying to use a handler to switch between the two modes but cannot seem to get it to run.
I was wondering if someone could suggest another way to strobe the camera LED or if they could try to find something wrong with my code.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I'm really new to android programming.

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;


public class MyAlert extends Activity {
private Handler mHander = new Handler();

private boolean mActive = false;
    private boolean mSwap = true;   
    private Camera camera;
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();


        private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {         
            if (mActive) {
                if (mSwap) {                    
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    mSwap = false;
                    mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 20);
                } else {
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera = Camera.open();
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    mSwap = true;
                    mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
                }
            }           
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startStrobe();
    }

    private void startStrobe() {        
        mActive = true;
        mHander.post(mRunnable);


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, stopping preview and releasing the camera is enough to switch flash off.  But real problem is that devices behave differently and not always as advertised.

Comment: Thanks!    For device compatibility I know my device supports the FLASH_MODE TORCH. And for other devices I would use .hassystemfeature and try to set a variety of different strobe functions applicable to their device. Right now I'm just concerned with getting this code to work.